# Programmatically stack child views in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app I'm trying to mimic an SMS messaging application's conversation view where sent messages align to the left margin, and received messages align to the right. I'm using a custom `RelativeLayout` to achieve the left/right alignment, and I'm adding the `TextView`s dynamically at runtime, by calling a method on my custom `RelativeLayout`.

The problem I'm having is that as I'm adding the `TextView`s that follow the first one, they are being placed one on top of the other (at the same x,y) instead of being stacked vertically (increasing y).

Here's my code that adds the `TextView`:

```java
TextView txt = new TextView(mContext);
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params =
    new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(sent ? ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT : ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);  

// make sure this message is positioned below the last one
if (getChildCount() > 0) {
    params.addRule(BELOW, getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1).getId());
}

txt.setLayoutParams(params);
txt.setText(msg);

addView(txt);
```

My custom `RelativeView` is defined thusly:

```xml
<com.foo.bar.ConversationLayout
        android:id="@+id/loConvo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: A LinearLayout with vertical orientation, wrapped in a ScrollView would serve you best for this.

Comment: You are probably better off using a ListView with two different row layouts (one for sent, one for received).

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Karakuri, but as @vikram pointed out, I think the simplest way (which is what I ended up doing) is a `LinearLayout` with `TextView` children whose `gravity` property is set to `LEFT` or `RIGHT` depending of if the message was sent or received.

Comment: The problem is if you end up with (for example) 100 messages, you will have to put 100 TextViews inside a LinearLayout. This doesn't make sense when maybe only 6 or 8 even fit on screen--it's a wast of memory and will slow down your application as your message threads get very long. ListView is designed specifically for this usage because it recycles views once they are scrolled off screen.

Comment: @Karakuri, that's actually very true. I'm at the point of doing some rapid prototyping and am not using any persistant storage yet, which is when I tend to start thinking about ListViews and performance. Well taken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see is that you are not setting any `IDs` for the `TextViews` you are adding. So, when you call:

```
params.addRule(BELOW, getChildAt(getChildCount() - 1).getId());
```

`getId()` returns `NO_ID`.

From documentation on `View` class: `getId() returns a positive integer used to identify the view or NO_ID if the view has no ID`.

`NO_ID is used to mark a View that has no ID`.

Try setting IDs to your TextViews using either `setId(yourGivenId)` or `setId(View.generateViewId())` and see if that helps solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that IDs aren't set automatically. I'm working on API version 14, which doesn't have the `View.generateViewId()` static method, but I was able to achieve the same result by just having an incrementing counter as part of my class.